# How do I automatically enable Num Lock at the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, numlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force numlock to be on on boot at login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/force-numlock-to-be-on-on-boot-at-login-screen)

I want to automatically enable num lock (i.e. light is on), and use LightDM as my desktop manager.

How can I do that?