# How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?

Tags: login-screen, numlock

I am trying to force numlock to be on upon initial boot at the login screen on Ubuntu 12.04. The only solutions I have found so far switch numlock on only after initial login.

I'm looking to force numlock to be on when the login screen is displayed, and before the user has logged in. Can anyone assist?

Comment: is it during login screen on lightdm or after logging in under unity? cause i know solution to both

Comment: *From darryn.ten* -- NOT an exact duplicate, as I need numlock on BEFORE I login not after.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 using Gdm3 see @Faisal answer

Comment: If you want to enable numlock during cryptdisk boot password prompt in plymouth: https://superuser.com/a/1085795

Comment: To enable numlock for SDDM, add `Numlock=on` under the `[General]` section. See `man sddm.conf`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

On many machines, you can set whether or not <kbd>Number Lock</kbd> is turned on on boot, in the BIOS settings (accessible when you first power on the machine).

Otherwise, there are a number of ways to enable (or disable) <kbd>Number Lock</kbd> in software, depending on your specific needs. [The most useful ways are listed here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock)

If you want <kbd>Number Lock</kbd> turned on when Ubuntu starts (not before that on the GRUB menu, and not afterwards when logging in, and not just for specific virtual consoles), then install `numlockx` and make the initialization script `/etc/init.d/rc.local` use it to enable <kbd>Number Lock</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install numlockx
sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

<sup>Source: [NumLock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock), by [Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License), last line taken verbatim (as [this source permits](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).</sup>

Comment: So I followed the instructions over at the wiki page you linked to. I did the update command you list here. I did `sudo apt-get install numlockx`. But I didn't use the y option. Is that necessary? Didn't say anything about it over at the wiki page so I didn't do any of that. I rebooted and everything but Numlock is still disabled at boot and at login screen. Will try the update command. Other than that, am I missing something else here? The option "default numeric keypad keys" from keyboard preferences doesn't concern boot settings so I didn't enable that. Should I?

Comment: This did not work for me. Answer by +luvr did however.

Comment: This no longer works on Xubuntu LTS 12.04.

Comment: -y option is for force answer "Yes" if apt-get question about to install it. BECAREFUL WITH THIS: sometimes -I think here it is not the case, at least not in my case- there is some cases when apt-get says that something is needed to remove; in that cases apt-get will ask you confirm that action. But, sometimes remove packages automatically using apt would cause several problems on your machine. As an example sometimes ask you for remove some graphical packages that are use for GUI'S. Even sometimes it has asked me to remove gnome-desktop and some gpu drivers...that will really messed up SO

Comment: On newer systems, you need to edit your ~/.bashrc file.  Add line `numlockx on`.

Comment: kubuntu 20.4 error `sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/init.d/rc.local
sed: can't read /etc/init.d/rc.local: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 43):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Ensure that numlockx is installed:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install numlockx
   ```
2. Edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
   ```
3. Add the following line to the file:

   ```
    greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit Nano.

Comment: How can I just verify that numlockx is installed? Should it appear on a dash search?

Comment: Do I have to remove `greeter-session=unity-greeter` or the user-session=ubuntu` from the file (lightdm.conf)? Or just the greeter-setup-script line below them?

Comment: Yup! This worked like a charm! Unlike the complicated instructions and commands given in the accepted answer. Thanks! I also enabled the option "default numeric keypad keys" as shown below.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 this method prevented the display of the login screen on my machine. After the initial display of the Ubuntu logo, the monitor was simply showing that there is no signal (I tried to reboot a couple of times but it always ended up the same). Not knowing what else to do, I booted the system from a live USB and removed the line from lightdm.conf. After that the system loaded up again just fine.

Comment: @cascaval I had the same problem. What fixed it for me was installing the lightdm greeter (`sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`) then modifying the config so it used unity as before (edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and change the line to `greeter-session=unity-greeter`). THEN you can add the `greeter-setup-script` line, as described by @luvr.

Comment: This also worked for me on Xubuntu LTS 12.04.

Comment: While I know this trick worked for me in past versions, it no longer seems to works in 14.04. Adding this line to lightdm.conf breaks the login process, sending me to Low Graphics mode and preventing a login with Nvidia drivers. Removing this line fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't have the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` But I have this `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/70-linuxmint.conf` and it works!!! :D

Comment: I agree with prior comments that this edit may and has indeed created undesired problems with low graphics/Nvidia and I could not login until I reverted the change.

Comment: kubuntu 20.4 error :`Command 'gksudo' not found`

Comment: Flexible solution!  I don't use lightdm, but added this to my fluxbox startup script.  However numlockx does require window manager of some sort...hence the "x".

Answer (score 24):

## 14.04

Yes, use `locate` command as follow:

```
locate 50-unity-greeter.conf
```

The output is:

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

So, the file you need to edit is the above file.

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
gksu gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Add this line at the end of file:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Comment: What's the difference between /usr/share/lightdm/ and /etc/lightdm? Wouldn't the settings in the former folder be overwritten with updates, while in the second they wont or did I misunderstand the meaning of the folders?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: You are absolutely correct. Radu, I would suggest that you edit your answer accordingly. Editing a package file which is not under /etc can't be anything but a temporary hack.

Comment: This one worked for me

Comment: This is the closest answer that helped me.  I use `Xubuntu 14.04` and the file was `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-xubuntu.conf` and I added the `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on` to the end of that file and it worked great!  +1 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: in 16.04 beta2 this will lead to this problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: I don't have that file, I only have these: `50-disable-log-backup.conf`  `50-guest-wrapper.conf`    `90-nvidia.conf`
`50-greeter-wrapper.conf`     `50-xserver-command.conf`  `90-slick-greeter.conf`

Comment: It did work on Ubuntu 16.04! Nice...

Comment: in Ubuntu 16.4, i found file "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf" and it worked after correctly edited the file.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 (for my system) the config file was -- `50-ubuntu.conf`.

Answer (score 18):

**For Enabling it on Login Screen**

First, ensure that numlockx is installed, by typing these in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Then, edit the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

**For Enabling Numlock by Default after Logging In..**

1. In Dash Search for *Keyboard Layout* and open it
2. In the window that opens on the ottom right there is *Options*, click on it.
3. Under *Miscellaneous compatibility options*, Enable *Default Numeric Keys*.

[image]

Comment: it's not this case, i make this procedure by the way. I press the button "Num Lock" and immediately it's goes off, "don't stay on". I had checked the keyboard and it's ok in other machine and other o.s. I change the keyboard to an older ps/2 keyboard to test. It seems that works, ie, there is some problem with USB keyboard in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: what is a Dash Search? my mine is ubuntu 16.4, and i have not seen Keyboard Layout options (searched under settings, only for keyboard, and it did not have the 'default numeric keypad keys'.

Answer (score 7):

> ## Ubuntu 18.04

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run commands

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
su gdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

That's it...

[Solution by](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/06/17/enable-numlock-tap-click-ubuntu-18-04-login-screen/)

> ## In Ubuntu 20.04

To Keep it on

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true
```

To Keep it off

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state false
```

You can configure the way you like.

Comment: I get: Command 'gdm' not found

Comment: This is the solution if you use Gdm3 in Ubuntu 18.04 (the last line is not needed)

Comment: I get `No such key “numlock-state”`

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Shouldn't be a problem if you update to 20.04

Comment: I'm using 20.04 and get the same error "no such key"

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Try the method for 20.04

Comment: doesn't work. Fwiw, I'm using a VM w/ virtual box, and it seems the host machine always has control over numlock

Comment: I was getting the "No such key" error in 22.04 when trying to set `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard`. The key was actually in "desktop": `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state true`.

Answer (score 6):

I have done this, and it worked for me.  First, make sure you have universe repository added.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Now that `numlockx` is installed, create a file named `Default` in `/etc/X11/` with these contents:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/X11/numlockx ]; then
    /usr/bin/X11/numlockx on
fi

exit 0
```

Turn off your <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> and reboot. Voilà!

Comment: doesn't work in 18.04

Answer (score 4):

**Xubuntu specific.**

Versions from 14.10 include a pkexec mousepad action.

Follow previous answers to install numlockx

Edit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf as root

Alt+F2 then

```
pkexec mousepad /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Add

> greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on

then save.

Answer (score 2):

Most BIOSes allow this to be enabled. You can check your BIOS for this feature.

OR

Go to : System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Miscellaneous compatibility options

Check "Default numeric keypad keys"

Sources : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little `bash` script which takes care of everything in an automated way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILE='/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
KEYVALUE='greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on'
sudo apt --yes install numlockx
grep --quiet "$KEYVALUE" "$FILE" || echo "$KEYVALUE" | sudo tee --append "$FILE"
```

Do not forget to first make your `bash` script executable with `chmod +x scriptname`, then execute it with `./scriptname`.

Comment: @Phantômaxx The fourth line in my script reads `sudo apt --yes install numlockx`

Comment: I didn't notice that.

Comment: Anyway, it didn't work for me (Ubuntu Studio 20.10). No automatic numlock at login.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using lightdm you can add a file `/etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf` with

```
[Greeter]
activate-numlock=true
```

That will enable numlock at the login screen. I have encountered a small bug in the panel LED applet that shows indicators for numlock, scroll lock and caps lock. If you use this method then the indicator will show off, despite numlock being on. If you toggle numlock it will show the correct status.

To fix this add a startup application with the startup application app and add this command.

```
bash -c 'numlockx off && numlockx on'
```

Of course you need to install numlockx.
If you do not use the indicator applet then you can probably ignore this last part.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 20.04: With all the different similar config files I couldn't believe it would just be that file. So I tried the setting in 10's of files. Then I found a settings panel `Login Window` , where I could just turn this on. Which writes `/etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf` with exactly that value. After which it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

19.04 DISCO DINGO

SETTINGS > KEYBOARD> BEHAVIOUR> GENERAL

[image: Num Lock state reset]

Comment: Is that for user setting **after** they log in?

Answer (score 0):

> From the K Menu, launch System Settings and click on Keyboard (Edgy users: K Menu -> System Settings -> Keyboard and Mouse -> Keyboard). You can see in the middle section the options for "NumLock on KDE Startup", where you can choose to Turn On, Turn Off, or Leave Unchanged.09.07.2021

a copy from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Mate 22.04 (Jammy Jelly) with lightdm and arctica-greeter you can edit the configuration with `dconf-editor` in `/org/ArcticaProject/arctica-greeter/`. This is the official way and requires to run dconf-editor as the lightdm user, which is a problem. Settings done here take no effect if done as root or user.
[image]

A workaround for this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arctica-greeter/+bug/1900633) is to create a gschema.override in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` with for example `sudo vim /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/99_arctica_greeter.gschema.override` and then recompile the schemas with `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

The schema could look something like this:

```
[org.ArcticaProject.arctica-greeter]
background='/home/user/Pictures/fuchs/snowfox.jpg'
activate-numlock=true
play-ready-sound=false
```

Add any other keys that you see in `dconf-editor` and adjust as required and then recompile the schemas.