# Setting "num lock" to be enabled by default?

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen)

Everytime I start Ubuntu I have to hit the num lock button which isn't a big deal but I so use it a lot and it would be nice to have it enabled by default.

Can someone tell me how to so this?

Comment: could you please search askubuntu 1st before making me waste my time ;-) This has been asked before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen and not even so long ago. Removed my answer...

Comment: Sorry I was on my mobile and didn't have the search function readily available... Next time though leave the snarky attitude at home, it makes for a much less hostile environment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock):

## Enable NumLock during startup

Enabling Numlock on startup can be done of several different ways. First install numlockx:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

## Place command with init scripts

```
sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/rc.local
```

## Enabling NumLock from startx

If you are not using a graphical display manager then add the following line to /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

```
/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

## Enabling NumLock for Virtual Consoles (TTYs)

If you use the virtual consoles regularly, then you will quite likely want to have numlock on for the TTYs after boot up. The status of numlock/scroll-lock/capslock can be manipulated with the **setleds** command. One way to guarantee that numlock will be turned on after bootup for the TTYs is to run **setleds** via **rc.local** (a script run after every runlevel change; which in particular runs after booting up). To do so add something similar to the following in the file /etc/rc.local:

```
# Turn Numlock on for the TTYs:
for tty in /dev/tty[1-6]; do
    /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < $tty
done
```