# Ubuntu 13.10 How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?

Tags: boot, 13.10, login, login-screen, numlock

I found this [How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen)
But after I performed this steps (luvr answer from Apr 29 '12 at 20:11 ):

Ensure that numlockx is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Edit the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

after theese steps I rebooted the PC, and I can no longer be run ubuntu.
Why ubuntu drastically limits the system setup options. Through the GUI and deny basic settings such as on Num Lock on the log screen. And user must look for different solutions which can damages their system. 
Thank you community very much :(

Comment: Normally, LightDM (greeter) would remember your last entry and numlockx is no longer needed. So if you activate num-lock at login (manually by pressing the NUMLOCK key on your keyboard), it should stay like this.

Comment: Have you tried BIOS settings?

Comment: yes I have it in the BIOS enabled

Comment: @MrVaykadji I try it but does not work. I have numlock always **off** in login screen. Even when I had turn it **ON** in the previous session.