# How Do you set up numlockx at startup in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lightdm, 14.04, numlock

In ubuntu 13.10 in order to install numlockx you had to run:
`sudo apt-get install numlockx`
After you install numlockx you had to run:
`gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
At the end of this file you had to enter `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on`
In 14.04 when you run `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` it opens up a blank file....
How do i set up numlockx in 14.04?

I have also tried to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen) but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

to the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`.

however this file will be overwritten when the unity-greeter is upgraded. For a more permanent solution, add these lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

to a seperate .conf file that you create in either the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` or in the `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` folder.

thanks Gunnar Hjalmarsson for pointing that out

Comment: No, don't do that. 50-unity-greeter.conf belongs to the unity-greeter package, and any changes will be overwritten next time unity-greeter is upgraded.

Comment: so what file should it be added to then? it tried adding it to the file/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf to no avail

Comment: in fact it does work, i had forgotten to include the [SeatDefaults] line before. thanks for the help

Comment: The best approach IMO is to create a separate .conf file, either in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` or in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`. Enabling numlock has nothing to do with unity-greeter, has it?

Comment: Thanks for responding. What is the unity-greeter about then, except for performing tasks that need to be done at the login interface?

Comment: unity-greeter is a greeter. The desire to enable numlock can be assumed to be the same if you use another greeter such as lightdm-gtk-greeter, right? It's lightdm itself you want to configure, not a particular greeter.

Answer (score 0):

For Lubuntu 14.04 I edited the file ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart and appended the line:

```
@/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file, but you need to add an extra line, so it looks like:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you edit the file located in the following directory you can change the way he login screen displays on Ubuntu 14.04.

" /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf "

Enter one the following commands:

1. ***sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf***
2. Now add: ***greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on***

or

If you elevate to a root terminal you can skip "sudo".

1. sudo su
2. Enter you administrator password
3. ***gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf***
4. ***greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on***

Either way it will get you to the same spot.

YOU CANNOT JUST NAVIGATE TO THE FILE AND OPEN UNLESS YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS THE "ROOT USER" WHICH IS NOT RECOMMENDED BECAUSE OF SECURITY ISSUES.

If you want to make it so you have to enter a username and password at the login screen add the following line to that same file as "root":

*greeter-show-manual-login=true*