# How to edit lightdm.conf file

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, numlock

I tried to activate numlock in the login screen using numlockx. The instruction point me to add this line

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

to this file

```
 /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

I tried to reboot. In the boot screen this line was shown.

```
ERROR: File /etc/init/lightdm.conf: syntax invalid:
init:lightdm.conf:62: Unknown stanza
```

Which means the added line. What should I do?

Comment: What is the source of your instructions? A link would help.

Comment: @Parto: Possibly this question, with a misleading answer, is the source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450776/how-do-you-set-up-numlockx-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You are right about that source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you edited the wrong file. I have a feeling that you are supposed to add that line to e.g. `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, which should (at least) contain:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Optionally you can use a dedicated file, e.g. `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/numlock.conf`, with the same contents.

Comment: There is no file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf indeed, but I decided to create that file and add those lines into it. It works. Also thank you for getting rid of that misleading answer.