# how to find a word in text files from a directory

Tags: command-line, directory, search, find, locate

Suppose that I have a directory with name _file and includes two sub directory like _1 and _2 and on each one I have some text files. I want to search a word like foo in one of these text files. How I can do that? 
I want to know which text files in the whole directory contain that word?

Comment: the question here shows two options to recursively search a whole directory for the occurrence of strings in textfiles: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460536/list-path-and-filename-where-some-text-used/460603#460603

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to use a terminal command (obviously, but that belongs to the basics of Unix like system learning, you can google that yourself), a given software or what ?

Comment: @begueradj I did not now there are any softwares for this. So I asked general;)

Comment: Please accept the answer by @soulsource as this is a minimalized solution, relative to the suggestion of installing extra software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Install `ack-grep` by typing `sudo apt-get install ack-grep`
3. Change to the directory you want to search under, and type `ack-grep foo`. it lists out all the matches in all files under that directory.

Comment: After install running `ack-grep soemthing` results error on my Ubuntu Desktop 17.

Comment: PS: the latest version just using `ack`, instead of `ack-grep`. So, for example, if you want to search `/home/luciano/Desktop/`, it would be, first go to the directory you want to search in, and then `ack /home/luciano/Desktop/`.

Answer (score 80):

If you don't want to  install additional software, you can simply use `grep` in the terminal. To recursively search through directories, you can use the `-r` option (see `man grep` for details). The syntax you are looking for is probably:

```
grep -r "[STRING TO SEARCH FOR]" "[DIRECTORY TO SEARCH]"
```

So, for instance if I want to search for the string "asdf" in all files in all subdirectories of "/tmp/testdir/" the command looks like this:

```
grep -r "asdf" "/tmp/testdir/"
```

The quotation marks are not strictly necessary, but if your string or directory path contains whitespaces, you otherwise would have to mask them using the \ character...

Comment: I'd like to add that on Xubuntu you don't need to specify the directory if you're looking for text in present working directory.

Comment: Don't need double quote strings for Darwin Kernel Version `22.4` (on my Mac Terminal) either

Answer (score 8):

You can use recursive `grep` with the `-l` flag to only print the file's name instead of the matched line:

```
grep -Rl foo .
```

Or, you can use `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l foo {} +
```

Or. you can use `extglob` and normal `grep`

```
shopt -s extglob
grep -l foo **/*
```

Answer (score 6):

Just install `gnome-search-tool` using `sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool`
Search in dash for 'search for files' and launch it.

See image below:

[image]

1. Leave the 'name contains' section empty.
2. Select your folder.
3. Unfold the 'select more options' part and choose 'contains the text' and then press add.
4. Type here the text you want to search for and click find at the bottom right corner.

Enjoy.