# how to enable the usage of number keys while using ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

I cannot use some of my keyboard keys while I can use the same keys in windows[I am dual-booting between ubuntu and windows] I have highlighted those keys which I cant get in ubuntu [image]
so in short how to get those keys work.

Comment: i am using the gnome version

Comment: Does pressing `Num Lock` have no effect?

Comment: thanks those keys are working now after pressing numlock

Comment: You want to have Num Lock enabled from the start. Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen