# how to enable numlock at login screen on ubuntu 14.04 lts (when you type password)

Tags: 14.04, numlock

Just that question. How to keep it on?

My pwd has numbers and it is weird to not type them on the numpad for me (tried and retried numlockx properly on many ways found on the net, no success)
p.s. on the bios everything is as it should (i have pwd on win 7 and numlock is on automatically).

Comment: See this answer for 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/442354/158442

Comment: unfortunately, it isn't a duplicate because that thing (numlockx) doesn't work. i have followed those instructions from your link as well as few other, but like i said, unsuccessful. is there ANY other way than the numlockx? and btw, thanks for the answer.