# Disable numlock at startup? Ubuntu 16.04 xkboptions

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, capslock, numlock

The numlock and capslock keyboard light toggling crashes my computer (this is not the subject of the question). I am trying to deactivate these two keys at startup. I modified the /etc/default/keyboard file with the following and it works for capslock:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

Is there an equivalent to this command for numlock? I could not figure it out.

Comment: According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html where it has all the options, the only thing close to the numlock is `grp_led:num` but that looks kind of confusing if it turns on or off the numlock.  I recommend using `numlockx` but changing the command to `off` found in the second answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen  or if the second one doesn't work, try the third answer.