# Desktop 18.04 always with Numlock on?

Tags: 18.04, numlock

Is it possible to start Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 always with Numlock on?
In 16.04 it works with the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-numlockx.conf`.

Comment: this is NOT duplicate.  Solution in meintoned question does not work anymore. It will brak login and you have to use nano from recorvery mode to delete line in that file. It was duplicate like year ago but not now.

Comment: Garrom - please add an answer to the linked duplicate. You should also add a title "18.04" to signify that the answer is for this version.  Thanks.

Comment: Solution >> https://askubuntu.com/a/1142127/155039